# HTML and CSS Brackets devTools

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

for some reason the chrome developer tools have given my code in brackets, a text editor for HTML and CSS, 722 errors even though the HTML and CSS is functioning properly. Do you know why? This may seem very basic but please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are running a document via Brackets. If you try to run it without Brackets you will see no errors (I mean to double click the document in its' folder).

Comment: Thanks. That worked but the website looked different in chrome, the zoom was set to 100% unlike brackets live preview where it set the zoom to 300% to make the webpage look whole? Do you know why chrome did not do this? It did not cover the whole page for some reason.

Comment: Well, it depends on your code and I am not completely sure when I am talking blindly. Please provide paste bin link.